# Angular 10 / Typescript - Property does not exist on type 'Object'.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm moving from Angular 1 to angular 10 finally. So I'm in the midst of learning typescript. Forgive me in advance for any mistakes. I have quite a bit of code but this is the gist of it here. I'm used to using dot notation in my api responses in angular 1 but angular 10 is throwing an error: **Property 'CreditApplication' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts**.

The code does execute and the data is available and working properly in my HTML view. There are no console errors in the browser. The html view is reading result.CreditApplication.PrimaryCustomer, but the error above is being thrown in the build and in vs code.

```
            this.api.getApplication(id).subscribe(result =>{
            if(result){
                this.primaryCustomer = result.CreditApplication.PrimaryCustomer;
                this.financeOptions = result.CreditApplication.FinanceOptions;
            }
          })
```

I have created an interface and am importing PrimaryCustomer, and assigning primaryCustomer to it as follows:

```
export interface PrimaryCustomer {
 SSN: string;
 Id: number;
 CustomerReferences?: Array<any>;
 FirstName: string;
 LastName: string;
 Locale?: string;
 OptOutStatus?: boolean;
 IncomeSource: any;
```

}

Then in the component:

```
primaryCustomer: PrimaryCustomer;
```

Snippet of the HTML view which works:

```
<strong>Bank Name:</strong> <span *ngIf="primaryCustomer && primaryCustomer.BankAccount">{{primaryCustomer.BankAccount.BankName}}</span>
```

I've researched this type of error and found a few clues here on SO, but not exactly my issue here. I hope this is clear enough. I'm thinking I need to typecast result, but not sure. Help is appreciated.

Comment: By default type of object is unknown. So you need to define type of result object to any or your interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what I ended up having to do is create interfaces for EVERY variable, so result, primaryCustomer and financeOptions. I had to format my api call line like below to implement the interface for result:

```
this.api.getApplication(id).subscribe((result : Result)  =>{
```

Once I had all the interfaces setup properly, which was a learning experience, all the build errors were solved. Thanks to those who commented.